# Bootstrap-Vue typings

Tags: typescript

I am using Bootstrap-Vue. In it's `package.json` it has an entry

```
"types": "src/index.d.ts"
```

and the `index.d.ts` file is where expected based off that.

How do I get my `tsconfig.json` to pick that up and recognize that?

I have tried

```
"typeRoots": [
"./node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/bootstrap-vue" ]
```

and even tried copying the file into the `@types` folder in my `node_modules`. Neither seems to have done the trick.

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where your `.d.ts` file is located, as long as it's in your project folder the IDE should pick it up. I do sometimes need to reboot VS Code before new `.d.ts` files are registered.

Comment: It's not the IDE I am concerned about, but the command line compiler `npm run build` gives the errors

Comment: what was your solution?